# How to tell typescript an object is guaranteed to have a particular (dynamic) property?

Tags: typescript

I have the following typescript code (well - more complicated, because it's in Vue so some of the pieces are reactive).

```
type A = {
  a: string;
}

type B = {
  b: string;
}

const getObj = function(useA: boolean): A|B {
  if (useA) {
    return { a: 'test'} as A;
  } else {
    return { b: 'test'} as B;
  }
}

const getKey = function(useA: boolean): 'a'|'b' {
  if (useA) {
    return 'a';
  } else {
    return 'b';
  }
}

const getValue = function(useA: boolean): string {
  return getObj(useA)[getKey(useA)];
}
```

There's a typescript error in `getValue` because it can't guarantee that the object from `getObj` will be the type that has the key returned from `getKey`.  Is there a way to refactor this with generics or something to avoid this error?  Alternately, can I tell typescript to ignore an error (like the comments that disable linting on a line)?  Or somehow use type assertions?  In the actual case there are more than 2 possibilities and using typeguards would be messy.

I understand why typescript doesn't like this, but I'm hoping to either find a non-typeguard way to do it or tell typescript I'm comfortable with the risk/guarantee the property will be there.

Also note that I can't put a common function in A/B to just return the value, because in the actual code, I don't have control over those types/objects.

Comment: [Function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) and [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) are the idiomatic solution in cases like this (and provide great [DX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience#Developer_experience)). You can use something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbv23m). Does that answer your question? If so, I can write it up as an answer — if not, what am I missing?

Comment: If you really want to refactor so the compiler can verify type safety, you'd probably need to follow the fix for [ms/TS#30581](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) as described at [ms/TS#47109](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), although having a `boolean` input makes it more weird and complicated. It looks like [this version](//tsplay.dev/mA80PN), which is , but it's as close as we can get to leveraging compiler type checking here.  I'd probably rather just use type assertions in this case, but if you want me to write up an answer explaining this, let me know.

Comment: Yes @jsejcksn, that playground helped.  In fact, it doesn't even require all of the detailed typing of getObj and getKey... it was sufficient to change getValue body to:  
   return getObj(useA)[getKey(useA) as keyof typeof getObj];

This probably doesn't guarantee safety, but it was the simplest answer to eliminate the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to help the compiler understand the correlation between the return types of the two functions given the same input parameter:

```ts
function getValue(useA: boolean): string {
  return getObj(useA)[getKey(useA) as keyof typeof getObj];
  //                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  //                                   type assertion
}
```

You can also use [function overload signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) to provide narrower, specific return types correlated with their input parameters — this will improve type correctness and also improve [developer experience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience#Developer_experience) when using a code editor with interactive feedback, (like [IntelliSense](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense) in VS Code or the TypeScript playground).

Here's a complete example:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#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)

```ts
type A = { a: string };
type B = { b: string };

function getObj(useA: true): A;
function getObj(useA: false): B;
function getObj(useA: boolean): A | B;
function getObj(useA: boolean) {
  return useA ? { a: "test" } : { b: "test" };
}

function getKey(useA: true): "a";
function getKey(useA: false): "b";
function getKey(useA: boolean): "a" | "b";
function getKey(useA: boolean) {
  return useA ? "a" : "b";
}

function getValue(useA: boolean): string {
  return getObj(useA)[getKey(useA) as keyof typeof getObj];
}


// Other examples:

const o1 = getObj(true);
    //^? const o1: A

const o2 = getObj(false);
    //^? const o2: B

const o3 = getObj(true as boolean);
    //^? const o3: A | B

const k1 = getKey(true);
    //^? const k1: "a"

const k2 = getKey(false);
    //^? const k2: "b"

const k3 = getKey(true as boolean);
    //^? const k3: "a" | "b"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have the getObj function return a generic type T and then cast its return value if you are comfortable with the risk that the property might not be there in runtime.

```
type A = {
  a: string;
}

type B = {
  b: string;
}

const getObj = function(useA: boolean): T {
  return useA ? { a: 'test' } : { b: 'test' };
}
```

later in the code:

```
const aObj = getObj(true) as A;
console.log(aObj.a);
const bObj = getObj(false) as B;
console.log(bObj.b);
```

Note that types go away at compile time, so, if at runtime, for whatever reason, property a does not exist on aObj or b does not exist on bObj, those values will be undefined, and you'll be passing undefined values around, which could result in errors.

alternatively, if you want to ensure that the objects have their respective keys and values, you can do something like this:

```
const aObj = getObj(true);
if (aObj.a === undefined) {
    // handle error
}
```

For compeleness, for the getKey function, you can actually type the result with a type that only returns a or b like so:

```
const ABKeys = ['a', 'b'] as const;
type ABKey = typeof ABKeys[number];

const getKey = function (useA: boolean): ABKey {
    return useA ? ABKeys[0] : ABKeys[1];
}
```

Comment: I don't think this approach actually helps the case of wanting to do:
obj = getObj(variableObjType)[variableKey]  where variableObjType and variableKey are known to match but not known what they are.